# How can I print with DOSbox using printer's settings

Tags: printing, emulation, dosbox, dot-matrix-printer

I have a program that runs on Dos, so I use DOSbox, SVN-Daum version, to run this program.
Every function seems working fine except for the printing function.
The problems are DOSbox use their own font in its directory with other print settings in its configuration.
I want the printing output to match the printer's settings (dot-matrix printer with preset font and size).

How can I print with DOSbox using dot-matrix pre-setting from the printer?

Thank you.

Comment: Printing functions must be programmed.  It sounds like DOSBox has implemented a printing solution, that does not meet your printing requirements.

Comment: Try [WinPrint](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winprint/).